# When using EJS script within span tag, why span tag class does affect result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This code works

```
<span>  
<% if( !first_name && !last_name ) { %>    
  login required!  
<% } else { %>  
  Hello. <%= first_name %> <%= last_name %>  
<% } %>  
</span>
```

BUT This code keep showing 'login required!' message

```
<span class="call">  
<% if( !first_name && !last_name ) { %>  
  login required!  
<% } else { %> 
  Hello. <%= first_name %> <%= last_name %> 
<% } %>                                                        
</span>
```

There is some style tag about class 'call' which is
`span.call{"margin-right:4%"}` , I solved this problem in this way.

```
<span style = "margin-right:4%">                                    
<% if( !first_name && !last_name ) { %>    
   login required!  
<% } else { %>  
   Hello. <%= first_name %> <%= last_name %>  
<% } %>  
</span>
```

But why second code doesn't work properly?

Comment: It could affect, what is the style behind class?

Comment: EJS doesn't care about class attributes, so there's something else going on.

Comment: There is simple style tag : span.call{
 margin-right:4%;
}    But I don't know why this affects result